# How can I root my Moto G2?

Tags: rooting, motorola-moto-g2

I want to root my Moto G2 (running Marshmallow). I've never tried this before, so please tell me exactly step by step.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download [the latest SuperSU zip file](https://download.chainfire.eu/supersu-stable) and save it to your device at the root of the internal storage.
2. Download and install the [Android SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) and the [latest Motorola drivers](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481).
3. Enable Developer Options on your device by going to Settings → About and then tapping the build number 7 times.  Then go into Developer Options (again under Settings) and enable USB Debugging.

   [image: screenshots]

   [image: screenshots]
                                                                                    <sup><sup>[source](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm)</sup></sup>
4. Unlock your bootloader.  **This will wipe your data.**

   - Connect your device to your PC, open a Command Prompt / shell, and run:

     ```
     adb reboot bootloader
     ```
   - Wait for the device to reboot, then run:

     ```
     fastboot oem get_unlock_data
     ```
   - Enter the resulting code at [this Motorola site](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-b)  (making sure to format it as it says).
   - Enter the resulting key from that site in another command:

     ```
     fastboot oem unlock <key>
     ```
5. Download [the latest TWRP image](https://dl.twrp.me/titan) to your PC and flash it:

   ```
   fastboot flash recovery twrp-<version>-titan.img
   ```
6. Reboot your device, repeat step #3, then run:

   ```
   adb reboot recovery
   ```
7. From TWRP, choose Install and then select the SuperSU zip file you obtained in step #1.  Follow the prompts to flash the package and then reboot your device.

You are now rooted!